# How To Create "Publish Over SSH Plugin" Config (Add SSH Servers,Key etc) through pipeline script In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

My parameterized Jenkins build has a stage which copies a file to the remote host using the "Publish Over SSH" Plugin. As a prerequisite, I need to manually configure "Publish Over SSH Plugin" with SSH Key, SSH Servers, etc through Jenkins portal.
Is there any way to make these configurations programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is not a way to manually specify the servers programmatically using the "Publish Over SSH Plugin" as it only uses the servers that have been already been configured in the global configuration of your Jenkins instance. (This can be read about on the Jenkins Step Documentation for the [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/publish-over-ssh/) underneath "configName")

However, there is another plugin designed by some engineers at Cerner that does allow you to programmatically define the SSH Key, SSH Servers, etc. The [SSH Pipeline Steps](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/ssh-steps/) plugin is much more appropriate for your use case so you can copy files over to remote nodes with the **sshPut** step described in the plugin.

If you find yourself needing more information and/or examples with this plugin, I highly recommend checking out [Cerner's blog](https://engineering.cerner.com/blog/ssh-steps-for-jenkins-pipeline/) talking about the plugin and why it was made. Taking a look at the [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ssh-steps-plugin/blob/master/README.adoc) repo might help you as well.